Isometry between the Klein model and the Hyperboloid model
Contextualization: Let $(\mathbb{H}^n,h)$ be the $n$-hyperboloid model for the hyperbolic geometry, where
$$\mathbb{H}^n := \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_{n+1}^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 1\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
and $h:=\iota^*m$ is the inclusion of the Minkowski metric. Also, let $(\mathbb{K}^n,k)$ be the Klein model for the hyperbolic geometry, where
$$\mathbb{K}^n : = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\| < 1\right\},$$
$$ k_y(u, v) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} \frac{(1 - \|y\|^2)\delta_{ij} + y_i y_j}{(1 - \|y\|^2)^2} u_i v_j
$$
for all $y \in \mathbb{K}^n$ and for all $u,v \in T_y\mathbb{K}^n$ and where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.
Remark one: It's possible that I wrote $k$ incorrectly based on Wikipedia. If it's the case, please, let me know.
Problem: I need to find an isometry between these spaces. I constructed the stereographic projection $\pi: \mathbb{H}^n \to \mathbb{K}^n$ considering the focus as the origin and $\mathbb{K}^n$ as the disc at $x_{n+1} = 1$. In this case,
$$\pi(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{n+1}) = \left(\frac{x_1}{x_{n+1}},\frac{x_2}{x_{n+1}},\dots,\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\right),$$
whose inverse is
$$\pi^{-1}(y_1,y_2,\dots, y_n) = \left(\frac{y_1}{\sigma}, \dots,\frac{y_n}{\sigma}, \frac{1}{\sigma}\right),~~~~~~~\sigma := 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i.$$
According to this paper, this projection should be an isometry, but I can't prove it.
Otherwise, we know that the distance between two points in each model is given by
$$d_h (x,\tilde{x}) = \cosh^{-1}(-h(x,\tilde{x})),~\forall~ x,\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{H}^n,$$
$$d_k(y,\tilde{y}) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\left\langle y,\tilde{y}\right\rangle^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-\left\langle y,\tilde{y}\right\rangle^2}}\right),~\forall~ y,\tilde{y}\in \mathbb{K}^n,$$
for $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ being the Euclidean inner product. Then I tried to show that $\pi$ preserves the distances above, but I wasn't able to show it.
Question: Is $\pi$ in fact an isometry between $(\mathbb{H}^n,h)$ and $(\mathbb{K}^n,k)$? If so, how can I prove it? If not, which would be the "most natural" isometry in this case? Thank you very much for the aid.

On page 169-171 of this book, it is shown explicitly for $n=2$, which can be generalized for general $n$.

This is explained in this beautiful exposition.

Thank you very much! I solved it using the idea present in the file suggested by @Deane! But the book recommended by @Basics is very nice and useful. So, I've already added it to my reading list! Again, thak you very much.
